# A particular overloaded conversion operator

Tags: c++

I'm staring at the following code snippet, trying to understand what's going on, or at least how to name what i'm seeing to google it up.

```
struct A {
    A *m_ptr; 
    typedef A * (A::*T);
    operator T() const {
        return &A::m_ptr;
    }
};
```

I figured out that `operator T()` is an overloaded conversion operator to type `T`, while type `T` is a typedef to represent `A*(A::*)`. Now,

- what exactly is `A::*`?
- what's the difference between that and `A*`?
- and what sence does the `A::` in the `return` statement make?

Comment: "how to name what i'm seeing" - it's a pointer-to-member.

Comment: Yeah, yay, that's exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the difference between that and `A*`?

`X*` is the address of an `X` object, whereas `X Y::*` is a pointer-to-member that points to a member of class `Y` of type `X`.

The difference is that a pointer is the address of an object.

A pointer-to-member is more like an offset, because it's not an actual address, it is relative to some object. It tells you how to get a member given some object. You can't dereference a pointer-to-member on its own, you have to combine it with an object to dereference it.

You create a pointer-to-member by using the `&` operator on a qualified-id, so `&x` means "take the address of the object `x`" but `&Y::x` means get a pointer-to-member for the member `x` of class `Y`.

You dereference a pointer-to-member by combining it with an object (or pointer to object) using the `.*` operator (or `->*` operator).

e.g.

```
struct Y { int i; int j; };

int Y::* memptr = &Y::i;
Y y;
int& i = y.*memptr;
memptr = &Y::j;
int& j = y.*memptr;
```

Answer (score 3):

> what exactly is `A::*`?

It's a pointer to a member of `A`. Type type `A* (A::*)` is a pointer to a member of `A` of type `A*`.

> what's the difference between that and `A*`?

It's a pointer to an object of type `A`.

> and what sense does the `A::` in the return statement make?

`&(A::m_ptr)` is a pointer to the `m_ptr` member of an object.

---

An example program that explores the idea a little bit more:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A *m_ptr1; 
    A *m_ptr2; 
    typedef A * (A::*T);
    operator T() const {
        return &A::m_ptr1;
    }

    A(int d) : data(d) {}
    int data;
};

int main()
{
   A::T ap1 = &A::m_ptr1;
   A::T ap2 = &A::m_ptr2;

   A a1(10);
   A a2(20);

   a1.*ap1 = &a1; // a1.m_ptr1 points to a1.
   a1.*ap2 = &a2; // a1.m_ptr2 points to a2.

   a2.*ap1 = &a2; // a2.m_ptr1 points to a2.
   a2.*ap2 = &a1; // a2.m_ptr2 points to a1.

   std::cout << "a1.data: " << a1.data << std::endl;
   std::cout << "a1.m_ptr1->data: " << a1.m_ptr1->data << std::endl;
   std::cout << "a1.m_ptr2->data: " << a1.m_ptr2->data << std::endl;

   std::cout << "a2.data: " << a2.data << std::endl;
   std::cout << "a2.m_ptr1->data: " << a2.m_ptr1->data << std::endl;
   std::cout << "a2.m_ptr2->data: " << a2.m_ptr2->data << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a1.data: 10
a1.m_ptr1->data: 10
a1.m_ptr2->data: 20
a2.data: 20
a2.m_ptr1->data: 20
a2.m_ptr2->data: 10
```

Comment: I would reword the last sentence to be clearer, `&m_ptr` is "a pointer to the `m_ptr` member", `&A::m_ptr` is a pointer-to-member

Comment: Quickly deleted my comment above because my immediate understanding was actually far from complete, as your answer explained.